# Change the background color Favorite Tags

Tags: feature-request, design, bookmarks

Unlike the other sites, including that of Mathematics and Physics (see image below)

[image]

the background color of the favorite tags for TeX.SE is a very pale pink color that is barely visible.

Can I change it or should I ask moderators or site managers? I have attached the image.

[image]

**ADDENDUM 10/08/2018**

Although the site has changed in graphics the pale pink color has remained the same. Why was there no change after my report? Can we not all do something about it? And after the main site administrator have changed the colors of the tags from blue to pink. Weak choice.

Comment: It looks yellow to me, but I agree it is very pale. It always makes me think these posts are dimmed/greyed out. It took me a while to realise they were just posts and a while longer to realise they matched my 'favourite' tags. So the highlighting is essentially disfunctional for me.

Comment: I very much agree with you and vote positively your comment. I have to incline my head to see the background well. In your opinion, is there a solution? I hope my question has not been useless.

Comment: I suspect this is not configurable, but I really have no idea. In general, the site is not very accesibility-friendly: it should allow all kinds of things to be configured, ideally, if only to accommodate people with visual impairments of various kinds. (Not to mention less-than-ideal screens etc.) But that would undermine the site 'design' and 'branding' :(.

Comment: Site design/theme is site-wide configuration, not user-personalized. However, issue related to site's design/theme is on-topic on meta though, and if it's compelling enough, SE designers *might* (expect in [6-8 time unit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/241919)) adjust the color.

Comment: @AndrewT. I have seen yesterday that it has been changed the color of the score (lightgray) but yet nothing for the color the background of the favorites.

Comment: I must agree that on my monitor and with my eyes it is quite hard to see the difference between a highlighted and a normal question. It gets better if I turn the brightness up a lot, but on lower settings it is really hard for me to distinguish.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it yourself and you can select whatever colour you want:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        StackExchange TEX, fav bgr colour
// @match       *://tex.stackexchange.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( `

     .tagged-interesting{
         background-color:#d5dde9 !important;
     }


` );
```

[image]

Comment: I thank you but I don't understand your code even though I voted for it positively. How should I make it work? I wonder why all these unnecessary changes on the site that worked fine. Some retouching was necessary, but not all of these upheavals.

Comment: You need a browser extension called GreaseMonkey (or TamperMonkey, on Chrome and friends) to apply this trick. Alternatatively, you can use an extension called Stylus and just add the CSS code ( the three lines starting at `.tagged-interesting`) to a new style for the site.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen  I have now understood. Sorry, but why didn't the site operators apply it right away? The contrast of the celestial background is better.